# Laravel: Exclude Route from URL History

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route that responds with images from private storage - but only for authorized users. This is because they cannot be in public storage for security reasons.

Now I have a form (using Blade) where these images are loaded as a small preview of the current value. When the resulting request is validated and has errors, Laravel's FormRequest class will redirect to `$this->redirector->getUrlGenerator()->previous()`.

Since the images were loaded after the form, the user is redirected to the image URL instead of the form, where validation errors would be shown.

#### My question:

How can I exclude one specific route from the URLGenerator's history, so that the `->previous()` call will not return the image URL but the URL of the form?

Thank you :)

Comment: Show us some code for your logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem that works - in my eyes - better than the previously proposed answer.

I created a new middleware group in the `Kernel` class where I substituted the middleware `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` with an extending class that overrides the `handle` method. My method basically does the same as the original, but it does not call `$this->storeCurrentUrl($request, $session);`.

This way, any route with this middleware group will not be added to Laravel's URL history. Next, I registered a new route group in the `RouteServiceProvider` that uses my new middleware group.

This way, Laravel's default redirect to the previous URL works since all storage routes will not be included in the URL history.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same challenge requesting images from Amazon S3 through a controller which messed with Laravel's URL history. I came up with the following "hacky" one-liner:

```
request()->headers->set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

When this line is present in the image-serving controller, the `storeCurrentUrl()` in `setPreviousUrl()` won't get called. I registered a new middleware called "silent" to laravel so I can use it in a simpler way in the routing in `web.php`.

Answer (score 0):

- You should not depend on previous generated URLs from your site. This is a bad practice in my opinion.

  - Let's say you had a simple form on one page and another simple form on another page(which the user opened in another tab). Now, if the latter one was served later and user was filling the first form, then you would be displaying first form errors on the second form of the page which is very undesirable.
- Best option is make use of **named routes**. You would not have to depend upon URL route history anymore and is perfectly reliable to redirect a user to the form route itself. I am assuming you are using named routes, meaning, giving names to your routes. Something like below-

**Route:**

```
<?php

Route::get('/your-form-route',['as' => 'form-name-route','uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod']);
```

**Controller Method:(after submitting the form)**

```
<?php

class SomeController{
 public function processInput(Request $request){
   $validator = Validator::make(.....);

   ....
   ....
   if($validator->fails())
        return redirect()->route('form-name-route')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe was unclear before: I don't specifically implemented a redirect to the previous URL, the core of the Laravel framework does that by itself when using FormRequests. The `FormRequest` class implements a method `getRedirectUrl()` that will by default return `$this->redirector->getUrlGenerator()->previous()`. 
See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L140

I was looking for a solution that would work with the default Laravel classes.